# Gson JSON max size

Tags: java, json, gson, clob

I need to extract some data from a [Clob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html) and serialize it in JSON format.

**What's the maximum size Gson can handle?**

Here https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md I can just find
*"Strings: Deserialized strings of over 25MB without any problems"*

**Context**: I use..

```
ResultSet.getClob()
-> BufferedReader 
-> String singleLine 
-> StringBuilder 
-> String "jsonAttribute" to serialize
```

More in detail:

```
try{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( resultset.getClob(2).getCharacterStream() );
    String line;
    try{
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    }catch(IOException ee){
        // logger
        throw ee;
    }

    String jsonAttribute = sb.toString();

}catch(Exception xx){..}
```

Note: in my current code the limitation is Integer.MAX_VALUE

My solution will consit in using chunks of the data retrieved from the DB. I would like to know the theoretical max size that GSON can handle. I won't use a browser on the receiving side.

Comment: I don't know if there's such limit (IMHO, the only limit involved here is memory), but how about writing some unit test to test for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gson doesn't impose any limit. Nor it has any known arquitectural limitation.

I think the main problem you will face with your approach is loading the data into memory in the first place.

I recommend using Gson stream API to write the JSON as you read it from the database. Use a [`JsonWriter`](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2) and create and stream your JSON object.

```
Reader reader = resultset.getClob(2).getCharacterStream();
JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(someOutputStream);
copyStream(reader, someOutputStream);
```

Where `copyStream` could be something like

```
public static void copyStream(Reader istream, Writer ostream) throws IOException {
  char buffer[] = new char[2048];
  while (true) {
    int len = istream.read(buffer);
    if (len == -1)
      return;
    ostream.write(buffer, 0, len);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I confirm @sargue answer. I tried the following **test** and worked like a charm with the right amount of heap memory allocated to the jvm.

```
@Test
public void testGsonLimitss(){

    EntityHalConverter<HugeData> converter = new EntityHalConverter<>(HugeData.class);
    HugeData hugeData = new HugeData();
    converter.toJson( hugeData );
}

class HugeData implements HalResource {

    String big1, big2;

    public HugeData(){
        // big1 = StringUtils.repeat("X", 400000000); // 300 millions chars ~ approx 3 mb.  With  multibyte chars ..... 3.5 mb
        big2 = StringUtils.repeat("Y", Integer.MAX_VALUE-10);
    }
}
```

This is the converter I'm using (with Halarious) ..

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import ch.halarious.core.HalResource;
import ch.halarious.core.HalSerializer;
import ch.halarious.core.HalDeserializer;
import ch.halarious.core.HalExclusionStrategy;

public class EntityHalConverter <T> {

    private Gson gson;
    private GsonBuilder builder;

    private Class<T> paramType;


    /* HalConverter<ProgrammeData> halConverter = new HalConverter<>(ProgrammeData.class);
    */
    public EntityHalConverter(Class<T> paramType) {
        builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.setExclusionStrategies(new HalExclusionStrategy());
        this.paramType = paramType;
    }


    /* String jsonResult = halConverter.toJson( programmeData );
    */
    public String toJson( T result ) throws JsonParseException{

        builder.registerTypeAdapter(HalResource.class, new HalSerializer());
        gson = builder.create();
        return gson.toJson(result, HalResource.class);
    }


    /* ProgrammeData pcsProg = halConverter.convert( jsonString );
    */
    public T fromJson( String json ) throws JsonParseException {

        builder.registerTypeAdapter( HalResource.class, new HalDeserializer(paramType) );
        gson = builder.create();
        return (T)gson.fromJson( json, HalResource.class );
    }

}
```